# Chrome sees internet connection, Spotify doesn't

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, internet, spotify

I'm having a bizarre problem with an application on Windows XP. I can happily browse the internet in Chrome, but Spotify insists there is no connection available. Spotify used to work fine.

Some background. This may or may not be connected to the problem: Yesterday I was using an oscilloscope to study the electronics inside an induction hob. This caused the fuse in the induction hob to *explode* and trip the breaker for the mains ring. When I switched the power back on, the internet didn't seem to work on the PC any more. Not even in Chrome. After a lot of turning things off and on, I realised the internet was working. I get the [image: No Internet] icon on the task bar, and this in the Network Connections window:

[image: Network Connections]

I have tried re-enabling the Internet Connection.  Sadly, I can't remember what the settings were like before the power tripped, or whether the [No Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wTmz.png) icon was there either.

Any suggestions why suddenly one application can't see internet any more, while another does?

Comment: Can you check to see if crome is setup to use a proxy?

Comment: @richard - I don't think it is. In the LAN settings (since Chrome uses IE's settings) no proxy was set. I tried setting it up as our gateway, and Chrome still worked. I tried telling Spotify to use the gateway proxy, but that still didn't work.